# WPF: the right way to scale a path?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a path (looks like an oval):

```
<Path Data="Bla Bla"/>
```

Now I want to scale the path's width and height to whatever I like. I found a way:

```
<Grid Width="400" Height="50">
<Viewbox Stretch="Fill">
    <Path Data="Bla Bla"/>
</Viewbox>  
</Grid>
```

And this works, but I'm wondering if this is the most efficient way to do this? (I had to introduce a grid and viewbox to do this)

Comment: `<Path Stretch="Fill" Data="Bla Bla"/>` also works inside `<Grid>`

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Another way to Scale a Path is to use `RenderTransform` or `LayoutTransform`

```
<Path Data="Bla Bla"
      RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5">
    <Path.RenderTransform>
        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1.5" ScaleY="1.5"/>
    </Path.RenderTransform>
</Path>
```

Comment: Generally prefer a `LayoutTransform` so that when the `Path` grows, the space it takes up on a `Panel` will too.

Comment: @sixlettervariables: Yes indeed, unless for the scenarios where you want the opposite :) But as you say, in most cases `LayoutTransform` is the one you want you use

Comment: I also believe a LayoutTransform doesn't affect the stroke thickness whereas a RenderTransform does.

Answer (score 14):

just FYI, since ViewBox uses ScaleTransform inside it it's basically just as good performance-wise.

Answer (score 13):

You basically have 3 ways to scale a Path:

1. Wrap it into a ViewBox
2. Apply a ScaleTransform
3. Explicitly set a Width and a Height

Method 1. and 2. will yield the same result, while 3. is slightly different because the shape will change size, but the stroke will keep the original Thickness (so it's not really a zoom).

Method 1. would be appropriate when you have an area of a given size that you want to fill. On the other hand method 2. will be useful to enlarge (or reduce) the path by a given amount, for ex. two times the original size.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it programmaticaly, like
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a0d473fe-3235-4725-aa24-1ea9307752d3/how-to-rendertransform-in-code-behind-c?forum=wpf

```
kUIWEB:kArrow mArrow = new kUIWEB:kArrow(); 
mArrow.Width=30; 
mArrow.Height=30; 
mArrow.RenderTransformOrigin=new Point(0.5, 0.5); 


ScaleTransform myScaleTransform = new ScaleTransform(); 
myScaleTransform.ScaleY = 1; 
myScaleTransform.ScaleX = 1; 

RotateTransform myRotateTransform = new RotateTransform(); 
myRotateTransform.Angle = 0; 

TranslateTransform myTranslate = new TranslateTransform (); 
myTranslate.X = 12; 
myTranslate.X = 15; 

SkewTransform mySkew = new SkewTransform (); 
mySkew.AngleX=0; 
mySkew.AngleY=0; 

// Create a TransformGroup to contain the transforms 
// and add the transforms to it. 
TransformGroup myTransformGroup = new TransformGroup(); 
myTransformGroup.Children.Add(myScaleTransform); 
myTransformGroup.Children.Add(myRotateTransform); 
myTransformGroup.Children.Add(myTranslate); 
myTransformGroup.Children.Add(mySkew); 

// Associate the transforms to the object 
mArrow.RenderTransform = myTransformGroup;
```

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.